# What's the difference between ApplicationServices and RequestServices in Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpContext?

Tags: asp.net-core

In `Startup` class, I can add services in `ConfigureServices` method. When I want to get a certain service, there are 2 properties in HttpContext instance, `ApplicationServices` and `RequestServices`. I wonder the difference between them and how to use them properly.

Edit #1:
For example, in Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ICache, InProcessCache>();  // Line 1
    services.AddSingleton<ISystemClientResolver>(SystemClientResolver.CreateInstance); // Line 2
    services.AddScoped<SystemClient>(); // Line 3
    services.AddRvcBusiness(); // Line 4
    services.AddMvc(); // Line 5
}
```

If I don't call `app.UseRequestServices()` in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method, I can get `SystemClient` instance by `Context.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(SystemClient))`, but it's not per-request basis, it seems singleton and `Context.RequestServices` is null. Once I call `app.UseRequestServices()` like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRequestServices();
    // ...
}
```

`Context.RequestServices` is not null and I can get `SystemClient` instance by `Context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(SystemClient))` and the instance is per-request basis.

Comment: Note: `ApplicationServices` is no longer part of `HttpContext`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ApplicationServices` are for the lifetime of your app, while `RequestServices` are scoped to a particular request (`HttpContext`).  Furthermore, `RequestServices` can be null.  A special RequestContainer middleware is what initializes `RequestServices`:

`app.UseRequestServices()` will use the result of `ConfigureServices` as RequestServices

`app.UseServices()` and its overloads let you specify/modify the request services

Also if you use routing/or any security auth middleware, they will automatically ensure RequestServices are populated as well, since they rely on request scoped services themselves.

Comment: What do you mean for the lifetime of your app ? what about scoped services ? are they also for the lifetime ? doesn't make any sense. I also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146454/applicationservices-resolves-a-different-scoped-instance-in-net-core)