# ApplicationServices resolves a different scoped instance in net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using .net core 3.1 with this configuration :

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public void Work();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    readonly string MyGuid;
    public Foo()
    {
        MyGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public void Work() { Console.WriteLine(MyGuid); }
}
```

And this is the configuration :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>();
        ...
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IFoo foo, IServiceProvider myServiceProvider)
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Via ApplicationServices");
        app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IFoo>().Work();

        Console.WriteLine("Via IServiceProvider");
        myServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>().Work();

        Console.WriteLine("Via IFoo injection");
        foo.Work();

    }
```

Result are :

> Via ApplicationServices 27e61428-2adf-4ffa-b27a-485b9c45471d   <----different
> Via IServiceProvider c9e86865-2eeb-44db-b625-312f92533beb
> Via IFoo injection c9e86865-2eeb-44db-b625-312f92533beb

More , in the controller action , If I use `IserviceProvider` :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromServices] IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
     serviceProvider.GetService<IFoo>().Work();
     }
```

I see **another different** Guid : `45d95a9d-4169-40a0-9eae-e29e85a3cc19`.

**Question:**

Why does the `IServiceProvider` and Injection of `IFoo` in the `Configure` method yield the same Guid , while the controller action and `app.ApplicationServices.GetService` yield different ones?

There are `4` different guids in this example

It's a *scoped* service. It supposed to be the same Guid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

`IFoo foo` is resolved using `myServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>()` before both get passed into `Configure` method. So you're resolving same `IFoo` instance from the same `myServiceProvider` instance for the 2nd time.

`app.ApplicationServices` is special root service provider of the application. Parent of `myServiceProvider`. Thus it resolves different `IFoo`.

***Default behavior of `app.ApplicationServices` should be to throw exception when you try to resolve scoped service.*

**LONGER EXPLANATION**

If you have three dummy classes:

```cs
class Singleton { }
class Scoped { }
class Transient { }
```

And you register them as such in `IServiceConfiguration`:

```cs
public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<Singleton>();
    services.AddScoped<Scoped>();
    services.AddTransient<Transient>();
}
```

Now, you create your "root" `IServiceProvider` from `IServiceCollection` - in command-line app, it would look like this:

```cs
ServiceCollection sc = new ServiceCollection();
ConfigureServices(sc);
ServiceProvider root = sc.BuildServiceProvider();
```

*ROOT SERVICE PROVIDER BEHAVIOR* (equivalent to `app.ApplicationServices`):

If you now test `root`:

1. `root.GetService<Singleton>();` - every time it's called returns same object instance.
2. `root.GetService<Scoped>();` - every time it's called returns same object instance.
3. `root.GetService<Transient>();` every time it's called returns new object instance.

*CHILD-SCOPE SERVICE PROVIDER BEHAVIOR* (eg: `IServiceProvider` in `Configure` method):

If you now create child scope and use it's own `IServiceProvider`:

```cs
IServiceScope scope1 = root.CreateScope();
IServiceProvider sp1 = scope1.ServiceProvider;
```

1. `sp1.GetService<Singleton>();` - every time it's called returns same object instance which`root.GetService<Singleton>();` returns. `Singleton` is the same instance no matter from which scope you call it. It is resolved climbing the hierarchy of scopes back to the root service provider (scopeless one).
2. `sp1.GetService<Scoped>();` - every time it's called returns same object instance, but  not the same instance that `root` returns. Object instance is cached on the current scope. Every scope creates/caches it's own scoped instance.
3. `sp1.GetService<Transient>();` every time it's called returns new object instance, same behavior like for the root.

`root` scope is "special" only because it has no parent scope, so resolving scoped or singleton service from the `root` technically does the same thing - object instance returned is cached in the `root` itself.

This also explains why you cannot resolve service from `IServiceCollection` directly. `IServiceCollection` does not have hierarchy of scopes and caching infrastructure which `IServiceProvider` has. It just contains list of `ServiceDescriptor`. In addition, it would be unclear in which scope service instance should be cached.

*ASP.NET Core*

For ASP.NET Core root `IServiceProvider` is `app.ApplicationServices`. `Configure` method receives first child-scope created from the `root` - application-scope. For every HTTP request application-scope creates child-scope which is used to resolve all services and is itself injected in controllers and views of that HTTP request. It is also used to inject all other types in a controller constructor or a view.

**`IFoo` resolution**

So, your `foo` from `Configure` method is resolved using `myServiceProvider`, then they both get used as input parameters for `Configure`. Framework does something like this:

```cs
ServiceProvider root = sc.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
var appScope = root.CreateScope();
IFoo foo = appScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();
ConfigureServices(foo, appScope.ServiceProvider);
```

When you call `sp.GetService<IFoo>()` inside of `Configure` method it is identical to `appScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>();` that was already called from the outside. `root.GetService<IFoo>()` creates different `IFoo` instance, as it should.

*More ASP.NET Core:*

To prevent developers making mistake trying to resolve `scoped` service from the `app.ApplicationServices` and not realizing that it is application scoped (global), instead of being scoped to HTTP request, by default, ASP.NET Core creates root `ServiceProvider` using `BuildServiceProvider` overload:

```cs
ServiceProvider root = sc.BuildServiceProvider(validateScopes: true);
```

> validateScopes:    true to perform check verifying that scoped services never gets resolved from root provider; otherwise false.

However, this might depend on compatibility mode you're using. I'm guessing that's the reason why it allows you to resolve scoped service via `app.ApplicationServices`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update answer:**
For being able to provide you with the same instance, the DI engine will need to know the current scope.

The `Configure` method in the `Startup` class is called initially by the ASP.NET Core engine, not by a request from the user which is how a scoped service is meant to be used.

Now if you try this example instead:

```cs
IServiceScope scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope();

scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IFoo>().Work();
```

As long as you use the same `ServiceProvider` from the same `IServiceScope` instance, you will have access to the same `IFoo` object and will get the same GUID.

**Old answer:**
A scoped service is meant to be living for a short period (scope) and get removed when they are needed anymore.

From [Dependency injection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped)

> a scoped lifetime indicates that services are created once per client request (connection)

furthermore,

> Do not resolve a scoped service from a singleton and be careful not to do so indirectly, for example, through a transient service.

`app.ApplicationServices.GetService` will try to provide you a Singleton which is not what the service is registered as.

What you see is the expected behavior. If you need the service to have the same instance for the whole period of your application's lifetime, you will have to register it as a Singleton.

Read more about [the singleton lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#singleton) and change your code from `services.AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>()` to `services.AddSingleton<IFoo, Foo>()` if you need the same value everywhere.

Comment: I know what singleton is. And I don't want to change it to singleton. All I want to know is why scoped returned different guids in the SAME request

Comment: Also , I didnt consume transient nor scoped service within a singleton. So I don't see how it relates

Comment: Because every time you call the `GetService` or inject the instance, a new `scope` is initiated by the DI. You will have to keep the scope object to be able to get the same instance. I will update my answer.

Comment: "_Because every time you call the GetService or inject the instance, a new scope is initiated by the DI_" - not true. I can call a 1000 times getService within the same request ( when SCOPED) and i will get the same guid

Comment: Can you please  explain why in the same request : I get 2 differnt values in here : https://i.imgur.com/zzCTsDn.jpg and another value in here  - https://i.imgur.com/i7IdTTD.jpg , while it's the SAME REQUEST

Comment: Because by calling the `app.ApplicationServices.GetService` you are creating a new `Scope` and the `IFoo` instance and the `IServiceProvider` passed to the method are from the same `Scope` but different from the `ApplicationServices`'s.

Comment: `app.ApplicationServices.GetService` creates a new scope ?  I must confest that I didn't find this in the web. Also how come both in the picture : https://i.imgur.com/wxizqKl.jpg  - they are differnet  ?

Comment: First time doing a similar thing it took me a while to figure this out too. The issue here is that the `app.ApplicationServices.GetService` is called even before any requests are accepted by the website, meaning that the `Scope` of the requests can never be the same as the `Scope` of the `app.ApplicationServices.GetService`.

Comment: so ,  how come both in the picture : https://i.imgur.com/wxizqKl.jpg -  are differnet ?

Comment: Because when a controller action is being called, is way after the Configure method in the Startup class is completed and the scope created for that method is removed. A new scope will be created when the user is requesting a controller's action, hence being on 2 different scopes which provide different instances of IFoo.

Comment: Ok.... so now i'm left with this question : how come the rootscope `app.ApplicationService` is different than this one ? https://i.imgur.com/M0EmRLb.jpg .... I mean they should be the same , becuase they are not realted to a request.

Comment: I'm answering this from the top of my head, if I remember correctly, that's because the `ApplicationService` is created first (to be used by the hosted services for the host environment) and has its own scope. But then, the IServiceCollection which is created later, while initiating the Startup class, will have access to the Service types from ApplicationServices, but doesn't use the same scope. Therefore the instance it provides to the method is different than the one which ApplicationServices provides because they are from different scopes.

Comment: Why did they do it like this? (but why meme)....oh well..

Comment: Haha! I think it's down to the point where the Configure method on the Startup class is not meant to be used in that way. :)

Comment: "app.ApplicationServices.GetService creates a new scope" actually it does not create a new scope, its just in another scope, I added an answer

Answer (score 2):

The IApplicationBuilder "app" is created and **passed** to the Configure method.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0#the-configure-method

> IApplicationBuilder is available to the Configure method, but it isn't registered in the service container. Hosting creates an IApplicationBuilder and passes it directly to Configure.

On the other hand the IServiceProvider "myServiceProvider" is actually activated/created and **injected**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#services-injected-into-startup

> Services can be injected into the Startup constructor and the Startup.Configure method.

> Any service registered with the DI container can be injected into the Startup.Configure method

So we are in two different scopes, so the guid, as expected, is different.

Via ApplicationServices 27e61428-2adf-4ffa-b27a-485b9c45471d <---- created in scope "A"

Via IServiceProvider c9e86865-2eeb-44db-b625-312f92533beb <-- created in scope "B"

Via IFoo injection c9e86865-2eeb-44db-b625-312f92533beb < -- created in scope "B"

When you are in your controller each request will have it's brand new scope, a different scope than the ones discussed above:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped

It seems to me that you expected that also the guid in the controller to be the same, you should be aware that for each request an instance of your controller is created and a DI chain starts in a fresh scope for each request.

Comment: What are the situations where i will need to use IApplicationBuilder as service provider ?

Comment: How is this different than the previous answer? The bottom line is that the GUID changes because the instance is provided from different scopes. You haven't provided any new/extra knowledge.

Comment: I cannot imagin a real one, never had to, but I would say in a custom scenario where the code you execute in configure method needs to access a "state" created during the host creation by a non singleton service

Comment: Rojan I saw your edit to your answer after I wrote my answer. My answer gives reference about why the scopes are different referencing the docs